# /usr/bin/mail call in ExecStart not sending any mail

Tags: systemd

I have the following service configured:

```
[Unit]
Description=SCollector
After=NetworkManager.service

[Service]  
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/opt/scollector/scollector /opt/scollector/collectors || (echo '' | /usr/bin/mail -s 'scollector died' jharvey@stackoverflow.com && exit -1)"
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For some reason, that `mail` command never sends any mail when the `scollector` process exits with non-0. This works AOK when run on the command line, `/bin/sh` call and all. I've captured STDOUT and STDERR of `mail`, and it is throwing no errors. There is nothing in `maillog`.

What gives? Why won't it send mail?

Comment: your `ExecStart` runs `exit -1` when `scollector` exits with `0`. Is it ok?

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. I ended up not using any of the above, so I never ran into that `exit`. I'll fix it in the question regardless so it doesn't red-herring anyone.

Comment: try `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "false || (echo '' | /usr/bin/mail -s 'scollector died' jharvey@stackoverflow.com && exit -1)"`. Does it work? Which version of `systemd` are you using?

Comment: Nope. As indicated in my answer, the issue is caused by `systemd` nuking the double-forked `sendmail` call from `mail`. I'm on cent7, which uses `systemd 208`.

Comment: To reiterate: simply having `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/mail -s test me@gmail.com </dev/null"` will never send mail, unless you change the `KillMode` as indicated in my answer.

Comment: oh, sorry. I missed your answer:) Which version of `sendmail` are you using? works fine with `systemd 219`, `sendmail 8.14.4`

Comment: `mail` is calling `/usr/sbin/sendmail`, but that's just a shim over to `/usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix`. I'm on postfix 2.10.

Answer (score 7):

`/usr/bin/mail` performs a double `fork` to daemonize `sendmail` for sending the email. This `sendmail` proc gets reowned to `init`, so normally it wouldn't be affected by anything that happens with the original parent - except in the systemd case that reowned grandchild is still in the same cgroup as the original service. When `systemd` tears things down, it kills all processes within the cgroup, including the reowned `sendmail` process.

The `mail` command itself ran fine, but `sendmail` was getting killed by systemd before it had a chance to do its thing.

You can get around this by setting `KillMode` in the `Unit` section to `process` (the default is `control-group`). That will cause `systemd` to only kill the process which it directly fired.

Interestingly the way I stumbled upon this was through the use of `strace`. A normal `strace` revealed nothing, but the `mail` suddenly started working when using `strace -f`. `strace -f` was causing the main process to stick around until all of the children and orphaned grandchildren had wrapped up.

Comment: `-S sendwait` as in `cat /tmp/mailtext | /usr/bin/mailx -S sendwait -r from@example.com -s "My Working Mail" to@example.com` works for me

Answer (score 2):

The questioner has identified the problem; but xyr solution is a bodge, and xyr description of the mechanics is incorrect.

The `mail` command does *not* perform a double fork.  It forks just once, and the sendmail shim process is its immediate child that is not reparented to anything.  It simply chooses whether to `waitpid()` for that child or not, before it exits.

The same is true of the sendmail shim itself.  It does not double fork.  On some MTSes it doesn't even fork at all.  On others it forks just the once and chooses whether to wait or not dependent from some configurable "delivery mode" option.

The correct way to get around the problem is twofold:

1. Set `mailx`'s documented and standardized `sendwait` option.  That specifically addresses the problems of asynchronous enqueueing, by making `mailx` wait for the sendmail shim child process to finish.  (Sadly, even though this option has been around since at least 1986 and is documented for `mailx` in the SVID, bsd-mailx does not have it.  heirloom-mailx has it, though.)
2. Set whatever MTS is in use to use a synchronous queueing/delivery mode if it isn't using one already.

   - If using netqmail, do nothing.  netqmail's sendmail shim is always queued and synchronous, directly chain loading through `qmail-inject` to `qmail-queue` without forking at all.
   - If using Postfix, do nothing.  Postfix's sendmail shim is always queued and synchronous, forking once and waiting for `postdrop` to finish before exiting itself.
   - exim has the `-odf` command line option.

## Further reading

- ["Utilities: mailx: Internal variables in mailx"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mailx.html#tag_20_75_13_02).  *Shell & Utilities*.  Single UNIX Specification.  Issue 7.  IEEE 1003.1.  2013.  The Open Group.

Comment: Note: to set the mailx internal variable, add 'set sendwait' to /etc/mail.rc (at least that's where it is on CentOS 7)

Comment: I was able to add `-S sendwait` when calling mailx since I didn't want to change the system configuration, but needed to make my script work when called from a systemd service unit.